# How to preserve all Subgroups while applying nested groupingBy collector

Tags: java, java-stream, counting, collectors, groupingby

I am trying to group a *list of employees* by the **gender** and **department**.

How do I ensure all **departments** are included in a *sorted order* for each **gender**, even when the relevant gender *count is zero*?

Currently, I have the following code and output

```
employeeRepository.findAll().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender, 
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, 
                                              Collectors.counting())));

//output
//{MALE={HR=1, IT=1}, FEMALE={MGMT=1}}
```

*Preferred output is:*

```
{MALE={HR=1, IT=1, MGMT=0}, FEMALE={HR=0, IT=0, MGMT=1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve that, first you have to group by **department**, and only then by **gender**, not the opposite.

The first collector `groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, _downstream_ )` will split the data set into groups based on department. As it downstream collector `partitioningBy(employee -> employee.getGender() == Employee.Gender.MALE, _downstream_ )` will be applied, it'll divide the data mapped to each department into **two** parts based on the employee gender. And finally, `Collectors.counting()` applied as a downstream will provide the *total number* of employees of each **gender** for every **department**.

So the intermediate *map* produced by the `collect()` operation will be of type `Map<String, Map<Boolean, Long>>` - *employee count* by **gender** (`Boolean`) for each **department** (*for simplicity, department is a plain string*).

The next step in transform this map into `Map<Employee.Gender, Map<String, Long>>` - *employee count* by **department** for each **gender**.

My approach is to create a stream over the entry set and replace *each entry* with a new one, which will hold a **gender** as its *key* and in order to preserve the information about a **department** its *value*  in turn will be an entry with a **department** as a key and a with a **count by department** as its value.

Then collect the *stream of entries* with `groupingBy` by the *entry key*. Apply `mapping` as a downstream collector to extract the *nested entry*. And then apply `Collectors.toMap()` to collect entries of type `Map.Entry<String, Long>` into map.

> all **departments** are included in a **sorted** order

To insure the order in the nested map (*department by count*) a `NavigableMap` should be used.

In order to do that, a flavor of `toMap()` that expects a `mapFactory` needs to be used (*it also expects a `mergeFunction` which isn't really useful for this task since there will be no duplicates, but it has to be provided as well*).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employeeRepository = 
            List.of(new Employee("IT", Employee.Gender.MALE),
                    new Employee("HR", Employee.Gender.MALE),
                    new Employee("MGMT", Employee.Gender.FEMALE));

    Map<Employee.Gender, NavigableMap<String, Long>> departmentCountByGender = employeeRepository
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, // Map<String, Map<Boolean, Long>> - department to *employee count* by gender
                        Collectors.partitioningBy(employee -> employee.getGender() == Employee.Gender.MALE,
                                                  Collectors.counting())))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(entryDep -> entryDep.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entryGen -> Map.entry(entryGen.getKey() ? Employee.Gender.MALE : Employee.Gender.FEMALE,
                                               Map.entry(entryDep.getKey(), entryGen.getValue()))))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                 Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                 (v1, v2) -> v1,
                                                 TreeMap::new))));

    System.out.println(departmentCountByGender);
}
```

Dummy `Employee` *class* used for demo-purposes:

```
class Employee {
    enum Gender {FEMALE, MALE};

    private String department;
    private Gender gender;
    // etc.
    
    // constructor, getters
}
```

**Output**

```
{FEMALE={HR=0, IT=0, MGMT=1}, MALE={HR=1, IT=1, MGMT=0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to work on the result of your code:

```
List<String> deptList = employees.stream().map(Employee::getDepartment).sorted().toList();

Map<Gender, Map<String, Long>> tmpResult = employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender, Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, Collectors.counting())));

Map<Gender, Map<String, Long>> finalResult = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<Gender, Map<String, Long>> entry : tmpResult.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Long> val = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String dept : deptList) {
        val.put(dept, entry.getValue().getOrDefault(dept, 0L));
    }

    finalResult.put(entry.getKey(), val);
}

System.out.print(finalResult);
```

Probably readability or maintainability of code won't be good if you want to achieve result with one line of code.

However, there is one alternative if you don't mind to use third-party library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Map<Gender, Map<String, Integer>> result = Stream.of(employees)
        .groupByToEntry(Employee::getGender, MoreCollectors.countingIntBy(Employee::getDepartment)) // step 1) group by gender 
        .mapValue(it -> Maps.newMap(deptList, Fn.identity(), dept -> it.getOrDefault(dept, 0), IntFunctions.ofLinkedHashMap())) // step 2) process the value.
        .toMap();
```

Declaration: I'm the developer of abacus-common